# How to make the pjsip sample program work continuously?

Tags: c, pjsip

This is a sample app of pjsip-2.13:

simple_pjsua.c:

```
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>
#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjmedia.h>
#include <pjmedia-codec.h>

// #include <iostream>

#define THIS_FILE       "APP"

#define SIP_DOMAIN      "192.168.111.52"
#define SIP_USER        "1018"
#define SIP_PASSWD      "pass1018"


/* Callback called by the library upon receiving incoming call */
static void on_incoming_call(pjsua_acc_id acc_id, pjsua_call_id call_id,
                             pjsip_rx_data *rdata)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;

    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(acc_id);
    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(rdata);

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);

    PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "Incoming call from %.*s!!",
                         (int)ci.remote_info.slen,
                         ci.remote_info.ptr));

    /* Automatically answer incoming calls with 200/OK */
    pjsua_call_answer(call_id, 200, NULL, NULL);
}

/* Callback called by the library when call's state has changed */
static void on_call_state(pjsua_call_id call_id, pjsip_event *e)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;
    pj_status_t status;

    PJ_UNUSED_ARG(e);

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);

    PJ_LOG(3,(THIS_FILE, "Call %d state=%.*s", call_id,
                         (int)ci.state_text.slen,
                         ci.state_text.ptr));
}

/* Callback called by the library when call's media state has changed */
static void on_call_media_state(pjsua_call_id call_id)
{
    pjsua_call_info ci;

    pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);

    if (ci.media_status == PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE) {

        // When media is active, connect call to sound device.
        pjsua_conf_connect(ci.conf_slot, 0);
        pjsua_conf_connect(0, ci.conf_slot);
    }
}

/* Display error and exit application */
static void error_exit(const char *title, pj_status_t status)
{
    pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, title, status);
    pjsua_destroy();
    exit(1);
}

/*
 * main()
 *
 * argv[1] may contain URL to call.
 */
int  main()
{
    pjsua_acc_id acc_id;
    pj_status_t status;

    /* Create pjsua first! */
    status = pjsua_create();
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error in pjsua_create()", status);

    /* Init pjsua */
    {
        pjsua_config cfg;
        pjsua_logging_config log_cfg;

        pjsua_config_default(&cfg);
        cfg.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
        cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
        cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;

        pjsua_logging_config_default(&log_cfg);
        log_cfg.console_level = 4;

        status = pjsua_init(&cfg, &log_cfg, NULL);
        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error in pjsua_init()", status);
    }

    /* Add UDP transport. */
    {
        pjsua_transport_config cfg;

        pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
        cfg.port = 5060;
        status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &cfg, NULL);
        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
    }

    /* Initialization is done, now start pjsua */
    status = pjsua_start();
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error starting pjsua", status);

    /* Register to SIP server by creating SIP account. */
    {
        pjsua_acc_config cfg;

        pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg);
        cfg.id = pj_str("sip:" SIP_USER "@" SIP_DOMAIN);
        cfg.reg_uri = pj_str("sip:" SIP_DOMAIN);
        cfg.cred_count = 1;
        cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str("*");
        cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("digest");
        cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str(SIP_USER);
        cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
        cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str(SIP_PASSWD);

        status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &acc_id);
        if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error adding account", status);
    }

    /* Wait until user press "q" to quit. */
    for (;;) {
        char option[10];

        puts("Press 'h' to hangup all calls, 'q' to quit");
        if (fgets(option, sizeof(option), stdin) == NULL) {
            puts("EOF while reading stdin, will quit now..");
            break;
        }

        if (option[0] == 'q')
            break;

        if (option[0] == 'h')
            pjsua_call_hangup_all();
    }

    /* Destroy pjsua */
    pjsua_destroy();

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that when I call this application from another computer, it answers the first time and there is no problem, but when the call is disconnected and I try to call a second time, it gives an invite timed out error.

When the call is terminated for the first time, it returns the following output:

```
01:48:49.457   pjsua_core.c  .RX 455 bytes Request msg BYE/cseq=32391 (rdata0xb4b0129c) from UDP 192.168.111.52:5060:
BYE sip:1018@192.168.111.136:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.111.52:5060;branch=z9hG4bK02606653-40cd-43ae-b710-1d8f12a16bfb;rport
To: <sip:1018@192.168.111.52>;tag=TamJaa3I3zpO.TOM-4ile-7GK-a.Lq0P
From: "1015"<sip:1015@192.168.111.52>;tag=jhswfwlt
CSeq: 32391 BYE
Call-ID: kigwojrrtyppifkupxhaqnvlhqxorjsihqxkwrqkakboisgswt
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:1018@192.168.111.52:5060>
User-Agent: Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK v1.3.6
Content-Length: 0


--end msg--
01:48:49.458   pjsua_core.c  .......TX 361 bytes Response msg 200/BYE/cseq=32391 (tdta0xb4b03c44) to UDP 192.168.111.52:5060:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.111.52:5060;rport=5060;received=192.168.111.52;branch=z9hG4bK02606653-40cd-43ae-b710-1d8f12a16bfb
Call-ID: kigwojrrtyppifkupxhaqnvlhqxorjsihqxkwrqkakboisgswt
From: "1015" <sip:1015@192.168.111.52>;tag=jhswfwlt
To: <sip:1018@192.168.111.52>;tag=TamJaa3I3zpO.TOM-4ile-7GK-a.Lq0P
CSeq: 32391 BYE
Content-Length:  0


--end msg--
01:48:49.458  pjsua_media.c  ......Call 0: deinitializing media..
01:48:49.458  pjsua_media.c  .......
  [DISCONNCTD] To: "1015" <sip:1015@192.168.111.52>;tag=jhswfwlt
    Call time: 00h:00m:01s, 1st res in 10 ms, conn in 836ms
    #0 audio PCMA @8kHz, sendrecv, peer=192.168.111.52:4014
       SRTP status: Not active Crypto-suite: 
       RX pt=8, last update:00h:00m:01.318s ago
          total 75pkt 12.0KB (15.0KB +IP hdr) @avg=41.5Kbps/51.9Kbps
          pkt loss=0 (0.0%), discrd=0 (0.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reord=0 (0.0%)
                (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev
          loss period:   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
          jitter     :   0.000   0.520   1.375   1.125   0.458
       TX pt=8, ptime=20, last update:00h:00m:00.001s ago
          total 31pkt 4.9KB (6.2KB +IP hdr) @avg=17.1Kbps/21.4Kbps
          pkt loss=0 (0.0%), dup=0 (0.0%), reorder=0 (0.0%)
                (msec)    min     avg     max     last    dev 
          loss period:   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
          jitter     :   0.000   0.150   0.375   0.375   0.183
       RTT msec      : 133.000 133.000 133.000 133.000   0.000
01:48:49.468  udp0xb4b0ad60  ........UDP media transport detached
01:48:49.468  pjsua_media.c  ........Media stream call00:0 is destroyed
01:48:49.468  udp0xb4b0ad60  .......UDP media transport destroyed
01:48:49.468            APP  ......Call 0 state=DISCONNCTD
warning: discarded first playback frame
warning: discarded first playback frame
warning: discarded first playback frame
warning: discarded first playback frame
warning: discarded first playback frame
warning: discarded first playback frame
01:48:50.468    pjsua_aud.c  Closing sound device after idle for 1 second(s)
01:48:50.468    pjsua_aud.c  .Closing samplerate sound playback device and samplerate sound capture device
```